# How to implement Ternary Operator a ? b:c without using if else & branching

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, ternary-operator

I want to implement Ternary Operator without using if else statement.
Need to implement using bitwise operator without using ternary operator & if else statement.

```
a= true --> res = b
a= false --> res = c
```

Comment: May you tell us what's wrong with if-else?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "implement ternary operator"? Are you writing a compiler?

Comment: This was Interview Question by NVDIA.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably mean that you want branchless source code. Note that the compiler is free to introduce branches in the assembly when there aren't any in the source code and vice versa.

Still, you can write `(!a) * c + (!!a) * b`. The assembly generated for this expression may or may not be branchless. MY compiler generates code for it that happens to be branchless (counting the CMOV instruction as branchless, which it is):

```
~ $ cat f.c
int f(int a, int b, int c) {
  return (!a) * c + (!!a) * b;
}
~ $ gcc -O -S f.c && cat f.s
…
    testl   %edi, %edi
    setne   %al
    movzbl  %al, %eax
    cmovel  %edi, %esi
    orl $-2, %eax
    incl    %eax
    andl    %edx, %eax
    addl    %esi, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
```

Comment: `!!` shouldn't be needed as `a` is apparently already of bool type.

Comment: @Lundin I will leave it because it is trivial to optimize out if `a` has type `_Bool`.

Answer (score 1):

`res = a ? b : c;` (perhaps add some parenthesis if a b or c are complex)

Comment: "**I want to implement Ternary Operator**"

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
a && ((res = b), true);
a || ((res = c), true);
```

[Added]

Let me assume you want to use only bitwise operators and `res`, `a`, `b`, `c` are all `n`-bit signed integers. Then you may want to try this:

```
res = (b & (((a | (~a + 1)) >> (n - 1)))) | (c & ~(((a | (~a + 1)) >> (n - 1))));
```

This can lead to undefined behavior if `a` is equal to minimum of `n`-bit signed integer, say, `-2^(n-1)`. In most platforms the results of overﬂows are reversible, though.

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
a?res=b:res=c
```

You've pretty much answered yourself in your question title.

Comment: I don't want to use ternary operator. I need to use other than if else and ternary operator.

Comment: @kapilddit are a, b and c numbers or some expressions with numbers?